# Best practice on download large file from cloud via Restful API

Tags: c#, azure, rest, api, cloud

I am trying to build a Restful API for user to download a zip file from cloud storage via my API.

Reasons to do this:

1. To prevent direct access to our internal cloud storage
2. To hide the technology being used (Brand of storage etc.)
3. To gain control over user request (Logging, validation)

There should be two way to do this on my APi:

1. Download as Byte[] and return
2. Download as temp file and read as byte[] and return

```
public static byte[] GetReportFile(GetReportRequest request, string refId)
{
    //C# byte limit is 2GB
    byte[] file = null;
    try
    {
        var report = ReportDao.GetReport(request.ReportId);
        var tempFilePath = new StorageService().DownloadByUriToTempFile(report.CloudPath);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    return file;
}
```

Both way require download of the file into memory or tempfile, wait the transmission of file complete (wait for user download finish or just deliver to HTTP???), and then memory is released or the temp file is deleted.

In case a file is sized 2 GB (let's assume this is large for the server to bear), Is there any way to minimize the loading on server side, may be something like download chuck by chuck, keep only a small portion of memory is being used.

Thanks in advance.

Jamie

Comment: You should use Streams and not download the whole thing in memory.

Comment: @Junnas thanks for your comment, I think my concept is wrong to download the whole thing at server side, would you happen to know any concrete sample that I can learn from it?

Comment: Here is one https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/11/streaming-zip-on-aspnet-core.html You can also find tutorials for C# streams pretty easily :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, one better way to do what you need would be:

1. Host the file in `private Blobs` in a Storage Account
2. When you get a HTTP request for the file, generate a `SAS` token for the Blob and return just the `SAS URL` of the file in response. The validity of the SAS token could vary with your requirement, but it would be wise to keep it to the bare minimum.
3. Thus, the client would essentially get a public URL, which would be valid for a limited time, to fetch the zip file without costing your services' resources.

Comment: Hi Bit, thank you for your answer. Would you mind telling me what would you do if the file for user to download is on you local drive and which is very large to read it all into memory.

Comment: That would actually be another question, but, I would use and have used a `MultipartStreamProvider` to upload it directly to the Blob Storage.